# How to connect my MongoDB Atlas account from PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb, connection, mongodb-atlas

I'm having trouble connecting to my MongoDB Atlas account.

Any ideas on how to do it?

```
<?php

    $server = "mongodb+srv://admin:<mypassword>@m001-basics-ivutt.mongodb.net/video?retryWrites=true";

    // Connecting to server
    $c = new MongoDB\Client( $server );

    if($c->connected)
        echo "Connected successfully";
    else
        echo "Connection failed";

?>
```

The script return nothing.

Comment: $server = "mongodb+srv://admin:<mypassword>@m001-basics-ivutt.mongodb.net/video?retryWrites=true";

 // Connecting to server
 $c = new MongoDB\Client( $server );

 if($c->connected)
  echo "Connected successfully";
 else
  echo "Connection failed";

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client(
    'mongodb+srv://kay:myRealPassword@cluster0.mongodb.net/?ssl=true&authSource=admin&serverSelectionTryOnce=false&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=15000"');

$db = $client->test;
```

for more details visit

https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/driver-connection/

Comment: I had already tried this and got nothing. Got this connection code from Atlas.